# change checkbox values using a javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an javascript array filled with values of checkboxes in a html file. How can i find the specific element and change checksign from jquery.

```
jQuery.each(substr, function() {
 var n = this;
 $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
 $('input[name='+n+']').attr('checked', true);
 });
});
```

**Substr** is the array filled with names. 
**substr = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}**
.The above code does not work. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `substr = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}` should be `substr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`.

```
jQuery.each(substr, function(i, val) {
 // val = a, b, c... etc
 $('input[type=checkbox][name="'+ val +'"]').attr('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Yes, added like that only for display purpose ;)

Comment: **it worked like this**

    jQuery.each(substr, function(i, val) {
    $('input[type=checkbox][value="'+ val +'"]').attr('checked', true);
    });